# How to amend a column based on duplicates in another and leave a unique value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet which has a lot of duplicates I need to cleanse but need to ensure the right data in another column is kept.

Data and desired outcome

[image]

Essentially in Column E there are duplicate values but these values could be duplicated any number of times, it is not the same amount each time.

In Column D for each record there should be either an A or B or blank.

Now the trouble is some duplicate sets have different values in column D. I need a way to remove all the duplicates from column E ensuring that each row in column E is unique while still ensuring the right value is kept from column D.

There are currently 3 different results in the raw data:

result 1: The duplicate sets (eg all HC0206 duplicates or HC0208 duplicates in column E) have the same value in column D (either all blank, all A or all B) - These are fine and don't cause a problem.

result 2: The duplicate sets have both blank and A in column D - When duplicates are removed an A must remain in column D.

result 3: The duplicate sets have both blank and B in column D - When duplicates are removed a B must remain in column D.

No duplicate sets have both A and B so we don't have to worry about that possibility.

I just can't work out how to ensure that when the duplicates are removed from results 2 and 3 above, that the letter remains and not the blank. If I could work out a way to ensure that all duplicate sets have the same value in column D then I could just remove duplicates without issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sort your data by column D ascending then use remove duplicates on the data tab.  You will want to highlight both D and E and any other data you want to keep.  Then use Column E as the duplicate criteria.  It will keep the first version of it and since you sorted the columns it will keep the ones that have something in column D if exists.

Comment: Oh Scott you marvellous person! I knew I had been overthinking it with trying to work out the right if commands and what not. Sometimes the simplest option eludes us, you have saved so much time! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Talking about overthinking.. you could realize it by formula in Office 365:

```
=LET(sorted,SUBSTITUTE(SORT(SORT(FILTER(D:E,E:E<>"","")),2),"",""),
     uniqueE,UNIQUE(INDEX(sorted,,2)),
     matchD,INDEX(INDEX(sorted,,1),MATCH(uniqueE,INDEX(sorted,,2),0)),
CHOOSE({1,2},matchD,uniqueE))
```

`sorted`-part makes sure column D:E are sorted by column 1, then 2 and blanks (that will result in `0`) are shown as actual blank. The sorting for later use.

`uniqueE`-part results in the unique values in column `E`

`matchD`-part shows the match of the unique values `uniqueE` in `sorted`. The first match in `sorted` column 2 will return the indexed value of `sorted` column 1.

matchD followed by uniqueE is your spilled result